# How can I test how my website displays on a particular mobile device?

Tags: mobile, user-behavior, usability-testing

I have taken a look at my Analytics and some devices perform better than others.

I would like to check the rendering of webpages on certain mobile devices without actually having to go out and physically buy one of these phones to test.

For example I would like to test a webpage on the following devices:

- Vodafone VF685 Smart Kicka
- Samsung GT-S53000 Galaxy Pocket
- Mobicel Retro

These are specific devices where the user engagement is poor compared to other devices and I would like to test if the webpage is being displayed/rendered properly.

Comment: It mainly really depends on what browser they are using. If its a built in one, then GL, as many prone manufacturers like to customize the WebViews, which leads to a lot of phones displaying certain page differently, supporting some things and not supporting other etc. Android default browsers are quite broken.

Comment: @MiChAeLoKGB Thanks, good point. Totally did not think of this.

Answer (score 3):

[Device Anywhere by Keynote](http://www.keynote.com/solutions/testing/mobile-testing) has the most comprehensive list of mobile devices for testing.

[image]

However, the comment stating that you should check the issues with the particular user agent browser renderings is entirely right in your scenario, and for this purpose I strongly recommend [BrowserStack](https://www.browserstack.com)